# Ant- Android building not create release version

Tags: android, ant

I've created a android project using eclipse. But I needs to do that same using command line. So, I use below command

```
 > android update project --path .
 > ant clean debug
```

Using above command its created-- Welcome-debug.apk and WelCome-debug-unaligned.apk
I also write the ant.properties file below-

```
   key.store=./mykey.keystore
   key.alias=MA
   key.store.password=mypassword
   key.alias.password=mypassword
```

now when I tried to build release version-

```
> ant relase
```

Unfortunately its not creating any release file. How do i create the release version using command line.

Expecting your response.

Thanks,
Pijman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: it should be `ant release`.

You don't need to do anything specific. `ant clean release` should do the trick. However, note the `clean` target: ant is lazy and is trying to skip as much of the work as possible - thus if you do not clean it will not recreate the class files and you will actually pack an apk featuring the debug compiled files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyway, its my typing mistake actually I typed 'ant release' but not getting any release version.

Comment: @pijushcse: please add the output when running ant. Also confirm that you tried with `ant clean release`.

Comment: Hello Boris Strandjev, Now i can create release-unsigned file. It was just missing of the proguard.cfg file.

Comment: Now, How can I make it release signed?

Comment: @pijushcse All you need is to provide the appropriate `ant.properties` file along with all the keystore data (like the one you mention). Make sure that you point to the keystore correctly (e.g. I think the path should be `../mykey.keystore`.

Comment: @pijushcse If I helped you solving your problem consider accepting my answer via clicking the empty check next to my answer. Optional additional reward is upvoting me - via pressing the up arrow to the right of the check. Consider doing the same with the answers to some of your other questions.